# JS/HTML range slider

Tags: library, javascript, html, forms

I need a library in order to show an input field (in a form) like the following:

[image: Grey slider in the middle of a horizontal line]

The value has to be between 0 and 5.

**Requirements:**

- Very light library (I don't need other components)
- Ability to customize the slider's color according to the input's value
- Compatible to Firefox 17
- JQuery library not needed

I already tried JQuery UI's one, but I'm looking for an alternative (especially if there is creative rendering alternatives of the slider).

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found one lib: [Dragdealer.js](http://skidding.github.io/dragdealer/)

It needs no depedency, and provide callbacks to allow customization of the slider when the handle is dragged (like color customization, ...)

An example of what I make:

[image]